# (AWS) Security implications of adding an exclusion for user:wsgi in sudoers

Tags: amazon-web-services, sudo, libreoffice, sudoers, ebextensions

While setting up a script to convert documents to PDF using libreoffice on AWS, I can't get libreoffice to `--convert-to pdf`without `sudo` as perhaps the user `wsgi` does not have write permissions to the `/opt/python/current/app` directory.

So I plan to solve this by appending the following line to the `/etc/sudoers` file:

```
wsgi ALL = NOPASSWD: /opt/libreoffice5.3/program/soffice.bin
```

As I want to automate this while deploying, in my `.ebextensions/01_packages.config` I have

```
container_commands:
  01_edit_sudoers_only_once:
        command: "echo 'wsgi ALL = NOPASSWD: /opt/libreoffice5.3/program/soffice.bin' >> /etc/sudoers"
        test: "test ! -f .sudoers_edited"

  02_mark_sudoers_as_edited:
        command: "touch .sudoers_edited"
```

Is there a potential security issue with this?

Comment: Does this belong on serverfault instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a significant potential security issue with giving a web service process the ability to invoke things with sudo.

Giving it permission to write to directories containing code would also be unsafe.

You really need to identify what's being denied and why that matters.  If error messages aren't sufficiently clear, you could use `strace` to observe the processes system calls and the resulting errors.

Comment: +1 for strace tip. I will try to figure out why it isn't working without sudo. Also I will write the PDFs into a separate directory outside the code directories.